# Running startup Command or Script in GNURoot Debian

Tags: android, debian, virtual-machine, autostart

Does anyone know how to auto-run a command or a script in GNURoot Debian when opening a new terminal window?
I'm trying to make make an SSH server run automatically when I open GNURoot,
so right now I'm manually typing:

```
service dropbear start
```

I found an "Initial Command" option in the GNURoot app preferences and typed the command in there, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Even worse it seems to make the new terminal window to open up in a non-working state where I can't run any command.

thanks!

Comment: Did answer solved your problem. You can accept. you will get +2 :)

Answer (score 0):

First root your device. Then find the file com...xml in /data/data/com.gnuroot.debian/shared_prefs/, change its initialcommand value to empty. Then your gnuroot should launch ok. I just met this question and checked androidterm source code to find this solution.